# How to maintain multiple cameras with different resolutions

Tags: workflow, scene

I'm developing a scene and want to have a few different camera settings: an isometric camera with render resolution x==y, and a wide-angle perspective camera with render resolution x>y, and maybe a couple more.

To start, I created a linked copy scene, adjusted the dimensions and set the active camera.

I continued developing my scene, adding objects, etc.

I now realized that the object links were setup when I added the new linked scene, but any new objects I add after of course only exist in the one scene where they were added.

1. Is there a way to maintain all objects being linked to all scenes?
2. Is there a better workflow I could be doing to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

This kind of situation is best handled with Python in my opinion since it's so simple to tweak and you can keep working on just one scene.

This simple script would change scene resolution, change camera (perspective/orthographic views are set within the camera), and start the render:

```
import bpy

bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = 1110
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = 870

bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.data.objects['camera1']
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].render.filepath = "C:/Test/"+"orthographic"
bpy.ops.render.render(animation=False, write_still=True, use_viewport=False)

bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = 220
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = 360

bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.data.objects['camera2']
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].render.filepath = "C:/Test/"+"perspective"
bpy.ops.render.render(animation=False, write_still=True, use_viewport=False)
```

To use make sure you change the resolution numbers, match the camera object names, change camera object to perspective or orthographic, match the 'Scene' to the name of your scene, change the filepath C:/Test/ to wherever you want to render.

Comment: Hm.. Inspiring. With this script, it should be possible to parse the objects, and if it is a camera and its name includes dimensions (eg. "Camera Overview 1920x1080") use it to set the resolution of its render. I'll dive into that asap.

Answer (score 0):

So I did it. It has been made! Get my very own add-on right here:
https://github.com/Gatada/MultiResolutionCameras

1. Download.
2. Open Blender Preferences (CMD+comma on MacOS).
3. Go to the `Add-ons` tab and click Install.
4. Browse to the downloaded python script and select it.
5. Enable the script, it is called: `3D View: Multi-Resolution Cameras`.

Now, I should mention that the add-on does not show the size of the camera in the 3D Viewport, but it's easy enough to preview by clicking the `Render Still`button in the Camera List.

I have started on code that will add a mesh to the view finder to represent the custom camera proportions, but so far not been able to get it to work.